# Using sudo tee in script sends junk to terminal also, bash Debian 11

Tags: bash, sudo, tee

I have a command line:

```
# Download and add the Nginx GPG key to verify the authenticity of the packages.
wget -O - https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo gpg --dearmor | sudo  tee /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg
```

That writes the correct data to the keyring, but sprays it to the terminal also. I tried changing sudo tee to sudo cat >, but '>' isn't part of the sudo, so I get a broken pipe.

I also tried various ways of redirecting stdout to /dev/null but still get broken pipe.

Is there a clean way to avoid tee sending the key binary code to the terminal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition (`man tee`) the `tee` command duplicates what it reads on *stdin* to its named file(s) as well as copying it through to *stdout*.

If you don't want the output just redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
... | sudo tee outfile >/dev/null
```